# Dynamicaly add methods from outside the class with a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

Two things I'm having trouble with. Adding a method from outside that references self. i.e.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, name): 
    self.name=name

def my_name_is(self):
  print("my name is %s" %(self.name))

setattr(A, my_name_is.__name__, classmethod(my_name_is))
a = A('bob')
a.my_name_is()
```

Because it tries to reference the name attr of 'A' rather than 'a'.

The other one is adding the function with a decorator i.e. something like a

```
@addMethod(A)
def say_hello_to(x):
  print("hello %s" %x)
```

rather some kind of equivalent to

```
def addMethod(cls, f) 
  setattr(cls, f.__name__, classmethod(f))
```

Comment: Why are you using `classmethod` if you want to reference `self`?

Comment: Just a note, `str.format()` is preferred to `%` formatting.

Comment: Would you happen to have a link to a post or more information about this? (str.format vs %)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: I mean as to why str.format() is considered preferable to % interpolation

Comment: @user3467349 From that link: `This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1**: what you're looking for is a method, not `classmethod`. In this case, a simple assignment would work:

```
A.my_name_is = my_name_is
```

**Question 2**: the expression following the `@` should return a callable, i.e. `addMethod(A)`
 should be a callable. This can be done like this:

```
def addMethod(cls):
  def method_assigner(f):
     setattr(cls, f.__name__, f)
     return f
  return method_assigner
```

Then this works:

```
@addMethod(A)
def say_hello_to(x):
  print("hello %s" %x)
```

(In this example, `x` will get the value of `self` when `say_hello_to` is called. I'm not sure I understand exactly the role of `x` in your cas, but hopefully this makes it clear how to achieve what you want. Perhaps you want `def say_hello_to(self, x):...` ?).

Comment: yes you're right, say_hello_to(self, x) is correct.

Comment: p.s. How could I define them so as not have to reference self in the original function declaration, or perhaps add self in dynamically with addMethod ?

Comment: the function you assign to the class should be a wrapper around `f`, which takes `self` and `*a,**kw` and passes `*a,**kw` to `f`.